# How to find the number of oberservations that fall into an interval?

Tags: r

I already got a table and a histogram by using these command:

```
> csvfile=read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";")
> hist(csvfile$fixed.acidity)
```

**Histogram**:

[image]

Now, I need to find the number of oberservations that fall into bin (7,8] in this histogram

I wrote a function:

```
num=0
for(i in fixedacidity)
{
  if((i>7)&(i<=8))
  {
    num<-num+1
  }
}
print(num)
```

but there is a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if ((i > 7) & (i <= 8)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What's wrong with my code and is there anything in the library to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hist()` with the argument `plot=FALSE`:

```
hist(x=1:100, breaks=10, plot=FALSE)
```

This will return a list. The data you seek is in the list element `counts`:

```
hist(...)$counts
```

In your specific case, this is:

```
hist(csvfile$fixed.acidity, plot=F)$counts[4]
```

Comment: Thanks. and why did the  warning message came in my code?

Comment: `if()` assumes your condition will be a vector of length 1.  You are feeding in a vector of a longer length.  If you want a vectorized version of `if()`, use `ifelse()`.

Comment: Given what you're trying to do, you might find something like this helpful:  `table(floor(csvfile$fixed.acidity))`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively one could use the tidyverse to get the number of observations in all groups:

```
if(!requireNamespace("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
csvfile <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";")

csvfile %>% 
  mutate(integer_group = round(fixed.acidity,0)) %>% ## Round to the nearest integer
  group_by(integer_group) %>% ## group by that variable 
  count() ## number of rows in each group
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this and getting the number of observations for all bins (with bin length being 1):

```
require(tidyverse)    
csvfile %>% count(interval = cut_interval(fixed.acidity,length = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to obtain the frequencies for the bins in a histogram is to print them at the top of the frequency bars by using the `labels=TRUE` argument in `hist()`.

```
 csvfile=read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";")
 hist(csvfile$fixed.acidity,labels=TRUE)
```

...and the output:

[image]